# Rails - adding a chunk of code in multiple files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a lot of js.erb files I want to put these 3 lines at the top of:

```
<% if @notifications.any? %>
  $("#action_modal_link").html("<%= j render 'actionmodal/action_notification' %>")
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to put the above code somewhere, once, and pull it remotely from within the individual js file?  In case I want to change it tomorrow, so I don't have to re-change all these files.

Doesn't look like a helper method, but I'm relatively new.

Comment: like if I could put in there &%CODE%& which would just reference that piece of code in some central location

Comment: like some global piece of code

Comment: Use a 'partial template'.

Comment: Right.   <%= render "actionmodal/partial_template' %> and then put the above code in it, which in turn renders the element replacement partial.   Well, no point in changing it now, in case I never have to change it, but if I do, I'll implement that, thanks!

Comment: You could also use a layout the same way you do with HTML views which would avoid the need to preface every file with `<%= render "actionmodal/partial_template' %>`. I have not actually done it with js.erb views but I imagine its possible by calling `render :my_template_name, layout: :my_layout_name`.